# Grouped select input with only one item

Tags: r, shiny, grouping, selectinput

I wanted to group my `selectInput` data as explained here: https://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/option-groups-for-selectize-input.html. Everything works except the situation where there is only one item in the group.

Here is an example (with correct first `selectInput` and strange second one):

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
    selectInput("country", "Select country", list(
        "Europe" = c("Germany", "Spain"),
        "North America" = c("Canada", "United States" = "USA")
    )),

    selectInput("country", "Select country", list(
        "Europe" = c("Germany", "Spain"),
        "North America" = c("Canada")
    ))
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

And the effect:

[image]

Do you know how to deal with that?

Comment: Use `list()` instead of `c()` to list the countries in each group -  ...  `"North America" = list("Canada")`

Comment: Great! @H1, put it as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `list()` instead of `c()` if there is a single element.  If there is more than one element you can use either `list()` or `c()`.

```
  ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput("country", "Select country", list(
    "Europe" = list("Germany", "Spain"),
    "North America" = list("Canada", "United States" = "USA")
  )),

  selectInput("country", "Select country", list(
    "Europe" = list("Germany", "Spain"),
    "North America" = list("Canada")
  ))
)
```

Answer (score 2):

I do not know why this happens but this is how it works for me

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput("country", "Select country", list(
    "Europe" = c("Germany", "Spain"),
    "North America" = c("Canada", "United States" = "USA")
  )),

  selectInput("country", "Select country", list(
    "Europe" = c("Germany", "Spain"),
    "North America" = c("Canada", "")
  ))
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

The only difference in code is that I added `""` here `"North America" = c("Canada", "")`. This gives me

[image: Output]

Comment: This works, thanks! But I think that H1 solution with `list` is better.

Comment: Yeah, I think so too. Did not see it before posting my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `list()` instead of `c()`, as in:

```
  selectInput("country", "Select country", list(
    "Europe" = list("Germany", "Spain"),
    "North America" = list("Canada")
  ))
```

The issue is with how R represents these things. `"x"` and `c("x")` are exactly the same thing, because in R, a scalar value is represented with a length-1 vector. To illustrate:

```
> identical("x", c("x")) 
[1] TRUE
```

So R has no way of distinguishing `"x"` from `c("x")`, but it can distinguish `"x"` from `list("x")`